# Context-Free Grammar for {w| w contains at least as many 0's as 1's and |w| >= 2} over the alphabet {0,1}.

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have first created the following CFG for the same number of 0's and 1's:

S → S0S1S | S1S0S | ε

To create more 0's than 1's, do I need to introduce a new variable such as the following?

S → SAS1S | S1SAS | 0A
A → 0A | 0

But it's not working!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the rule
$$S \to SAS1S \mid S1SAS \mid 0A,$$
is that, as soon as a $1$ is introduced, you are automatically spawning many more zeros all around the $1$. For example, you couldn't make the string $001$ with the given rules. Instead, consider creating the rule $S \to \varepsilon$ to allow each $S$ to be replaced with no $0$s (and no $1$s).

The above adjustment means that the string no longer satisfies $|w| \ge 2$, which we now need to address. What we'll need to do is replace $S$ with a new state, and have the starting state feed into it when we're comfortable that at least two symbols will be produced. Here's my suggestion:

\begin{align*}
S &\to TAT1T \mid T1TAT \mid 0A \\
T &\to TAT1T \mid T1TAT \mid \varepsilon \\
A &\to 0A \mid 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you!  I also came up with the following rule, where I am considering equal number of 0's and 1's or greater number of 0's than 1's:   $\begin{align*}
S &\to T0S \mid T0T \mid 0T1TS \mid 1T0TS \mid 0T1T \mid 1T0T \mid 00\\
T &\to 0T1T \mid 1T0T \mid 0 \\\end{align*}